# How can I test the BeforeInstallPromptEvent in Jasmine/Angular?

Tags: angular, testing, promise, jasmine, beforeinstallprompt

I'm writing a test for a dialog component, that handles the PWA install event prompted manually when a function is called. It will then resolve the promise coming back from the `BeforeInstallPromptEvent.userChoice` property.

However when I try to test this function I get an error from jasmine:

> 'userChoice.then is not a function'

Which I understand since I tried spying on that with a spyOn to then check the result.

I tried a few other things with Promises, since the userChoice returns a resolved promise (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent) but nothing has worked so far.

This is the function I am trying to test. The `BeforeInstallPromptEvent` is stored in the installEvent object that gets passed down to the component from the `app.ts` and then stored in data.

```typescript
this.data.installEvent.userChoice
            .then((choiceResult) => {
                if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
                    doSomething();
```

In my test spec I created a mockData object with the following:

```typescript
const mockData = {
  installEvent: {
    prompt: () => {},
    userChoice: Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      return { choiceResult: { outcome: "accepted" } };
    }),
  },
};
```

My test spec so far (after many different tries) is either this:

```typescript
it("should do something after user accepted", fakeAsync(() => {
 mockData.installEvent.userChoice.then((result) => {
      return result.choiceResult.outcome;
//this test returns true
      expect(result.choiceResult.outcome).toEqual("accepted");
    }); 
flush();
//but the function gets never called
expect(component.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Or with the `spyOn` function on the `userChoice` that produces the error:

```typescript
it("should do something after user accepted", () => {
spyOn(mockData.installEvent, "userChoice").and.returnValue("accepted");

expect(mockData.installEvent.userChoice).toBe("accepted)
expect(component.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

With that I managed to already test that the `data.installEvent.prompt` function is getting called.

But I don't know how to test that the `userChoice` Promise resolves to "accepted" and then triggers the if condition.

Please help me. Since I am a beginner regarding testing (in Angular) it would be nice to get an explanation of the method behind testing such Promises.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're resolving the promise already in `mockData` and the spy is not returning a promise.

Method 1

```
const mockData = {
  installEvent: {
    prompt: () => {},
    userChoice: Promise.resolve({ choiceResult: { outcome: "accepted" } }),
  },
};
```

```
it("should do something after user accepted", fakeAsync(() => {
 mockData.installEvent.userChoice.then((result) => {
      // return result.choiceResult.outcome;, remove return here and only test the assertion
//this test returns true
      expect(result.choiceResult.outcome).toEqual("accepted");
      expect(component.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled(); // make sure doSomething gets called
    }); 
flush(); // flush the promises
});
```

Method 2 (can't be done)

```
it("should do something after user accepted", () => {
  // you can't spy on userChoice since you can only spy on methods/functions and not variables
  spyOn(mockData.installEvent, "userChoice").and.returnValue("accepted");

  expect(mockData.installEvent.userChoice).toBe("accepted)
  expect(component.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Method 2 can't be done because you can only `spyOn` methods and functions and not properties.

Comment: thank you very much! this helped a lot. I discovered a tiny error still that I could solve (see above). now everything is working :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much @AliF50 for your answer!
I tried method 1 and it worked except for one little error I discovered afterwards:

```js
const mockData = {
  installEvent: {
    prompt: () => {},
    userChoice: Promise.resolve({ choiceResult: { outcome: "accepted" } }),
  },
};
```

needs to be

```js
const mockData = {
  installEvent: {
    prompt: () => {},
    userChoice: Promise.resolve( { outcome: "accepted" } ),
  },
};
```

since the structure of the `beforeinstallprompt.userChoice` property gives one object with the key outcome as seen in the if:

`if (choiceResult.outcome === "accepted")`

so the result in our example when resolving the promise in the test spec is equal to the choiceResult in the if condition.

After changing that everything is working now!

Comment: Glad that it's working. I can't believe I missed that.